# Neural Networks in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weka, text-classification

I have a textual data set which has been already classified. I have 7 available classes.

I used (Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis) WEKA in building the model. Also with this, I have trained and tested 3 different algorithms to determine which algorithm works best for my data set.

I tried Naive Bayes, J48 and Neural Networks (SMO) which are all available in WEKA's machine learning environment.

During training and testing, found out the ranking of three algorithms in terms of accuracy with the following:

1. Neural Networks - 98%
2. Naive Bayes - 90%
3. J48 - 85%

With the results above, I decided to use the Neural Networks and build the model. I created an application in JAVA and loaded the Neural Networks model built from WEKA.

However, my problem is, the model cannot predict the new data correctly. I am a bit confused as during training and testing I obtained a high accuracy but during deployment the accuracy rate is somewhat 40% only.

I tried to do this in C# and obtained the same results.
Below is a sample code I used.

```
   Instances test = null; 
   DataSource source = new DataSource("C:\\Users\\Ian\\Desktop\\FINAL\\testdataset.arff");
   test = source.getDataSet();
   test.setClassIndex(1); 

   FilteredClassifier cl1 = (FilteredClassifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("C:\\FINAL\\NeuralNetworks.model");        
   Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(test);      
   evaluation.evaluateModel(cl1,test);
   System.out.println("Results:" + evaluation.toSummaryString());   


    for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
        String trueClassLabel = test.instance(i).toString(test.classIndex());
        double predictionIndex =cl1.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));

        String predictedClassLabel;
        predictedClassLabel = test.classAttribute().value((int) predictionIndex );
        System.out.println((i+1) + "\t" + trueClassLabel + "\t" + predictedClassLabel);
    }
```

Any advise where do you think I did wrong?

Comment: How do you derive the performance figures like 40% ? Do you use the same test-data in both cases? When you say you got the same results using C# do you mean the same bad results as with Java or the same good results as with WEKA GUI?

Comment: I splitted my dataset. 80% training and 20% testing. I trained the model using the 80% dataset and obtained 99% accuracy. When I try to re-evaluate the model on the remaining 20%, I obtained 34% only. C# and Java obtains the same result of 34% when classifying new data, using the same testing set.

Comment: Same bad results as WEKA GUI.

Comment: There might be a chance that you are overfitting on your 80% and because of that the testing performance is bad. If I understand you correctly, the 99% accuracy is achieved by testing against the training data only, which is always a very optimistic guess on the true model performance. In the WEKA Gui you can either provide a dedicated test set (your 20%) or let WEKA automatically split a large data set in two user-defined portions like 80/20 or 90/10. Can you please try this and post your result, so that we know whether the issue is related to a code or a data problem.

Comment: I understand. Can you confirm if I need to load all the data as training set and use the Percentage Split as Test Option?

Comment: Yes, all data and then percentage split. Just let WEKA manage the splitting.

Comment: I combined my test and train data set. Run into WEKA and used the Percentage Split as Testing Option. Upon using 80% as training, I obtained 32% Correctly Classified Instances and 68% Incorrectly Classified Instances. Moreover, using 90/10 breakdown gives me 34% and 66% for Correct and Incorrectly classified Instances respectively. What do you think should I do to obtain more higher accuracy?

Comment: How do Naive Bayes and J48 perform on the test data? If they do much better than the NN then your NN algorithm is overfitting the training data as @Marcus suggests. If all three techniques do badly then perhaps the features in your dataset simply aren't predictive enough.

Comment: True - but then I would expect bad performance also on the test=training data scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our short chat in the comments, it seems obvious to me that you are overfitting on your training data. This is most likely caused by a neural network architecture which is too overpowered for the problem you are trying to solve. It can be shown that any function can be represented by a neural network with just enough degrees of freedom. Instead of finding a well generalizing solution, the NN memorized the training data during training, leading to a nearly perfect accuracy. But as soon as it has to deal with new data, it can not do it very well, as it didn’t find a proper generalization rule.
In order to solve this problem, you have to reduce the degrees of freedom of your NN. This can be achieved by reducing the number of layers and nodes in each layer. Try to start as simple as only 1 or 2 hidden layers with very few nodes. Then, keep increasing both, nodes and layers until you reach your best performance.

Important: Always measure performance with independent test set, rather than with the same data you trained the model with.

You can find some further hints on this issue [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html)